# How to unwrap an Option with its correct type in pattern matching?

Tags: scala

I have the following code that illustrates what I'd like to achieve but it doesn't compile ... I'd like to find out whether the `configMap` of type `Map` contains a key with value `"runOnGrid"` and if it does get its Boolean value.

```
val runOnGrid : Boolean = args.configMap.get("runOnGrid") match {
    case Some(value) : Option[Boolean] => value // <=== compiler error
    case None => false
}
```

but this doesn't work because I can't do `Some(value) : Option[Boolean]` namely I'm constrained to choose between matching by the value or by the type. To achieve this apparently I need better Scala kung fu ... can anyone advice?

UPDATE: meantime I figured this **horrendous** way to do it

```
val runOnGrid = args.configMap.get(("runOnGrid") match {
    case Some(value) => value.isInstanceOf[Boolean] && value.asInstanceOf[Boolean]
    case _ => false
}
```

UPDATE: ConfigMap is defined inside Scalatest as:

```
class ConfigMap(underlying: Map[String, Any]) extends Map[String, Any] ...
```

Comment: what's the type of `args.configMap`? Is it `Map[String, Any]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this `Some(value: Boolean)` value inside `Some` can be given a type annotation

```
val runOnGrid : Boolean = args.configMap.get("runOnGrid") match {
    case Some(value: Boolean) => value
    case _ => false
}
```

Comment: What about None? Is there a way to find out to witch Option type None originally belonged to?

Answer (score 3):

How about this workaround:

```
val runOnGrid : Boolean = args.configMap.get("runOnGrid") match {
  case Some(true) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting compile time error because you are mentioning type to case element, remove that and it will work,

So change to,

```
val runOnGrid : Boolean = args.configMap.get("runOnGrid") match {
    case Some(value) => value // <=== Changed
    case _ => false
}
```

Comment: Produces compiler error in Scala 2.10 `type mismatch; found : Any required: Boolean` besides it doesn't guard against a possible mistake where "runOnGrid" is of different type though I am not totally sure bypassing the runtime exception is a good thing

Comment: This works in scala 2.11, or as pamu said you can add type parameter to value so change will be, `case Some(value:Boolean) => value`

Comment: This answer assumes `configMap` has type `Map[String, Boolean]` which doesn't seem to be the case

Answer (score 0):

In case `configMap` has a type `Map[String, String]` (when you read configs from file), you can do:

```
val runOnGrid : Boolean = args.configMap.get("runOnGrid") match {
    case Some("true") => true
    case Some("false") => false
    case _ => false
}
```

Comment: why String rather than Boolean in the case statements?

Comment: in case when type of `configMap` is `Map[String, String]`, when you do  `configMap.get` you get an `Option` of type `Option[String]` so either `Some[String]` or `None`